# mount -a does not work, but mounting manually works

Tags: ubuntu, mount, fstab

lsb_release & uname

```
[wellbye@AY130622174524343529Z:~]lsb_release -a 
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu 
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 
LTS Release:    16.04 
Codename:       xenial

[wellbye@AY130622174524343529Z:~]uname -a  
Linux AY130622174524343529Z 4.4.0-105-generic #128-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 14 12:42:11 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=e2048966-750b-4795-a9a2-7b477d6681bf / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1     
/dev/xvdb1 /newdisk ext3 rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0 0
```

`sudo mount -a` has neither effect nor error, but manually mounting works:

```
 sudo mount -t auto /dev/xvdb1 /newdisk/
```

[image: df output showing /newdisk mounted]

what's the problem with `fstab` ?

Comment: [Please don't post images as text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), and also see the [editing help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help) about code blocks, they much better than quotes for terminal text dumps, if only because they keep line breaks where they are. You might want to [edit] your post to format it a bit nicer.

Answer (score 13):

I see you have the `noauto` flag set.  This *means* "don't mount with the -a flag"

From `man 5 fstab`

```
          noauto do not mount when "mount -a"  is  given  (e.g.,  at  boot
                 time)
```

Answer (score -1):

Below Should be format while mounting with UUID

```
UUID=UUIDNUMBER /directory ext4 rw,user,exec 0 0
```

Comment: Thats exactly what he did..`UUID=e2048966-750b-4795-a9a2-7b477d6681bf / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1`

Comment: The pasted `/etc/fstab` had two lines run together. I assume that was just a copy/paste error. The root filesystem is apparently mounting just fine, the problem is probably the `noauto` mount option on the second fstab line, as Stephen Harris wrote in his answer.